# Error in running javacv 1.5 in Android app

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, javacv

I trying to open an ONVIF WIFI CAMERA with FFmpegFrameGrabber for use in javacv in Android studio . 
I send frameGrabber.grabImage() to AsyncTask
in render method of SurfaceView:

```
        '''
        Mat mat0= new Mat(1080,1920,CV_8UC1);
        Mat mat=new Mat(1080,1920,CV_8UC3);;

         TestTask task = new TestTask();
        task.execute();
        mat = new ToMat().convert(frame);
        if (!(mat ==null)){
         cvtColor(mat, mat0, CV_BGR2GRAY);
         clahe.apply(mat0, mat0);
         frame = converterToMat.convert(mat0);
         bitmap = converterToBitmap.convert(frame);
        '''
```

this is AsyncTask:

```
         '''
        private class TestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void,                                                                                     org.bytedeco.javacv.Frame> /* Params, Progress, Result */ {
               @Override
        protected Frame doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {

        frame = frameGrabber.grabImage();
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "frameGrabber is grabImage");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        };
        return frame;
    }
```

'''
build successfully but i have this error at the run:

```
   Caused by: ...(address)...     couldn't find "libopencv_imgproc.so" at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1012)
```

for i make sure to use javaCV 1.5, i use these dependency at below:

```
        '''
        implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacpp', version: '1.5'
        implementation  group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv-platform', version: '1.5'
        implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'opencv-platform', version: '4.0.1-1.5'
        implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'ffmpeg', version: '4.1.3-1.5'
```

please help me , can i solve that?

Comment: Could you provide a list all the files that are getting packaged in the APK?